# returnig data from event listener function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have problems with wrapping event function. all comment in code bellow

```
<div id="someElem">
    <div id="someInnerEleme1">
        1
    </div>

    <div id="someInnerEleme2">
        2
    </div>

    <div id="someInnerEleme3">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

// first event listener(for main parent)

```
$("#someElem").click(function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
    // coordinate of clicked point
    var sceneData = [];
    sceneData[0] = x;
    sceneData[1] = y;
    console.log(sceneData);
});
```

second event listener(it's also fire function from first listener cause bubble effect)

```
  $("#someInnerEleme1").click(function(){
    // here i need coordinates of click on "#someElem"
    var sceneClicedData = wrapperFunctionToGetCoordinates();    
  });
```

in which way i can wrap first event lister, for getting coordinates here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep that structure you need to call `click` event on `#somElem` and store its x, y values somewhere.

```
/* new code */
var globalSceneData  = [];
/* /new code */

$("#someElem").click(function(e){
    var x = $(this).offset();
    var write = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
    // coordinate of clicked point
    var sceneData = [];
    sceneData[0] = x;
    sceneData[1] = y;
    console.log(sceneData);

    /* new code */
    globalSceneData = sceneData;
    /* /new code */
});
```

This call is nested below, you emulate `click` event and than can get stored values.

```
$("#someInnerEleme1").click(function(){
    // here i need coordinates of click on "#someElem"

    /* new code */
    $("#someElem").click();
    console.log(globalSceneData[0]);
    console.log(globalSceneData[1]);
    /* /new code */

    var sceneClicedData = wrapperFunctionToGetCoordinates();
});
```

I dont think it's nessesary, but there you have it. If you dont want to call event on previous element you could go with `$("#someElem").offset()` in  `$("#someInnerEleme1")` ([jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/))

Comment: thx, but it's not exactly what i need. sorry it's hard for me to explain on enlglish, but i'l try. i wana declare this "search coordinate" like a helper, which i can use in many independent functions. if i write it like in you answer, it will be need to declare it everywhere where i need to search coordinates

Comment: so i have same structure as you suggested in my old code version. i'am searching other way - is it possible to use click searcher in over scope like a outer independent function? here is my old example http://jsfiddle.net/kpblc/Uqv9L/